# Leafletoutput does not show in dashboardBody

Tags: r, leaflet, shinydashboard

Hi I am using shinydashboard to build some visualization for some raster files. I am use leafletOutput to display the map.

Under the first tabItem, where it is called 'KmeansOutput', I would like to display the leaflet map. When I do not include selectInput, it display the map, but once I include the selectInput, it do not display the map. I am not sure which part went wrong. Thanks in advance!!

Here is the UI section of the code:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)


sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("KmeansOutput", tabName = "kmeans", icon = icon("kmeans"),
                 selectInput("run1",
                             "SoilAllWeatherAll",
                             choices = c('4' = 1, '5' = 2),
                             multiple = TRUE)
),
        menuItem("HistoricalWeather", icon = icon("weather"), tabName = "weather"),
        menuItem("SoilMap", icon = icon("soil"), tabName = "soil")
    )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = "kmeans",
                leafletOutput("map", height = 700)
        ),

        tabItem(tabName = "weather",
                h2("weather")),
        tabItem(tabName = "soil",
                h2('soil'))
    )
)

    # Put them together into a dashboardPage
ui <- dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(title = "Genome Prediction"),
        sidebar,
        body)
```

here is the server:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>%
            addTiles() 
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a sub-item to your k-means siderbar item as follows.

```
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("KmeansOutput", #icon = icon("kmeans"),
             menuSubItem(
               "K-Means Map", tabName = "kmeans", icon = icon("calendar")
             ),
             selectInput("run1",
                         "SoilAllWeatherAll",
                         choices = c('4' = 1, '5' = 2),
                         multiple = TRUE)
    ),
    menuItem("HistoricalWeather", tabName = "weather"), #icon = icon("weather"),
    menuItem("SoilMap", tabName = "soil")#, icon = icon("soil")
  )
)
```